# Preserve fileExtension of drive file when uploading

Tags: google-drive-api

My app loads a file from google drive.  The fileExtension property is set to "peardeck" because the initial file name was "`Untitled Pear Deck.peardeck`".  Then my user renames the file to "`My Pear Deck`", with no extension in the title, but the fileExtension property is still `peardeck` in the metadata.

BUT: when I PUT to `/upload/drive/v2/files/fileID?uploadType=media`, the fileExtension is cleared to "".  This means that the Drive UI no longer offers to open the file with my app.

How can I stop the extension from being overwritten when I upload data to it?

Comment: can you make the association by mime type rather than by extension?

Comment: I think Google uses the extension to determine default apps, so it's important that the extension stay the same

Comment: Not so. You can use the API Console to associate by mime type. I have an app that is configured to open files of type "text/html", regardless of name/extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `?uploadType=multipart` and leave the metadata portion empty. See the [drive documentation for details on multipart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart).

Comment: Unfortunately I see the same behavior - the fileExtension property comes back blank.  I even tried setting fileExtension to peardeck in the metadata portion.

The funny thing to me is that the documentation says fileExtension is immutable.  Blah!

Comment: If I set title = "wtf.peardeck" in the metadata, then the file is renamed and the extension stays as .peardeck.

Answer (score 0):

My eventual solution / workaround was to forget about file extensions and rely entirely on mimetype, as pinoyyid suggested.  You can use `application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.yourcustomextension` if your app doesn't open one of the normal mime types.